# git repository not accessible read-only

Tags: git, open-source, cloudbees

CloudBees...

When I attempt to try to pull down the read-only git repo source, I get this error:

```
git clone git://git.cloudbees.com/sillyweasel/coffeescript-roo-addon.git
Cloning into 'coffeescript-roo-addon'...
fatal: remote error: access denied or repository not exported: /sillyweasel/coffeescript-roo-addon.git
```

Is there a reason why people cannot access my open source repo? The repo landing page offers up this URI as the public git repo.

Comment: Is the repo address correct? (down to the case, lower or uppercase)? And are the rights opened enough to allow anyone to access that repo?

Comment: Hi - this is indeed a bug with your account, we will let you know when it is resolved (shortly).

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug caused by a lockdown of file permissions in a recent release.
This has been corrected and your repositories are now anonymously readable where appropriate.

Comment: Excellent. I suspected something like that. +1